# How does ArangoDB determine how much RAM it has available?

Tags: arangodb

We're running ArangoDB in a CoreOS docker container on an AWS instance.

**This instance has around 1 gig of memory.**

However, when we load up the ArangoDB front end, **it *thinks* it has 2 gigs** of RAM available!
[image: ArangoDB thinks it has 2 gigs of memory available]

Clearly, it does not *actually* have this memory available to it, and hence crashes 10 times a day, as soon at the memory threshold crosses even a teeny bit over the 1 gig we physically have on our box.

How does ArangoDB determine that it has X amount of memory available? And where can this setting be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a `docker inspect` on that container. There will be a `Memory` entry in the `HostConfig` object. It will probably read `"Memory": 1073741824` while `"OomKillDisable": false`.

Indeed, `Memory: something` limits the resident size of the process in the container. If this is surpassed (and no swapping is possible), the process is shot down with something like this:

```
"State": {
  ...
  "OOMKilled": true,
  ...
}
```

`arangod` as a process cannot see the docker containers memory limitation. We see the host's, which might be higher like in your case. The only option is to raise the limit on the container or limit `arangod` memory usage via command line options.